# How can I identify the XPI file for a Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I am looking for the xpi file for Dashlane in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cjappv0w.default\extensions. It must be one of the ones with a random name, for example: {04a727ec-f366-4f19-84bc-14b41af73e4d}.xpi

How can I determine which one of these is the right one?

Comment: Under `Help` -> `Troubleshooting` all the extensions are listed with their IDs.

Answer (score 3):

If you look under `Help` -> `Troubleshooting Information` all the installed extensions are listed with their IDs.

[image: Firefox extensions]

(The screen shot is 64-bit FF65.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.02, UK English: the layout and text will vary with the OS, skin and language.)

Answer (score 3):

In `about:debugging`, you get the list of your extensions with their names and IDs.

Search you extension, and get its ID.

For example, uBlock Origin ID is `uBlock0@raymondhill.net` and Tab Center Redux ID is `{0ad88674-2b41-4cfb-99e3-e206c74a0076}`.

The XPI you search for is the one named `[your ID].xpi`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/839026)

Comment: In fact, the current answer doesn't neither. I clarified my answer. Thanks for the comment.